# Enum vs Static class in database table

Tags: c#, .net, enums, static, constants

I have to store in database

```
[Column 1], [Column 2-start datetime]
Version1_1,   01-01-2011
Version1_2,   01-01-2011
Version1_3,   01-01-2011
```

…
I have a class with two fields: the version name and the datetime (+id).
The version name represents the first column. It can be an **enum** or a **static class** with constants.

Regarding almost any scenario I understand enums are better. But then, The DB will store integers in the first column instead of string values. Which gives me a feeling of uncertainty.

Are the enums still the best option in this scenario? I don't see disadvantages in lacking clean string values in [Column 1] in database.

Comment: If you use EFCore, you can specify how to store an enum. By default it will be int (or the type the enum is a derivation of), but you can specify in the configuration to store it as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the values as integers in the database, you have several advantages:

- Less storage space required
- Easier querying without taking string comparisons into account
- Better query performance because integer comparisons are much faster than string comparisons

A disadvantage on the database side is of course the reduced readability, but considering the advantages, I'd prefer integers in the database.

On the C# side, enums let you have the best of both worlds: integers inside and at the same time text identifiers when working with the values.

Comment: I saw someone use static constants in this case for Identity Authorization:
[Authorize(Roles = UsersRoles.SUPERUSER + "," + UsersRoles.RoleA)]
I think for this case the readibility is more important and needs to be done with constants.